# Use more than one collectionviews in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios7

How can I use more than one collectionView in xcode? Is there anything I can assign to differentiate between one collectionView and another?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an ivar for each collection view and then do a pointer comparison in the dataSource/delegate methods.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewA;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewB;

@end
```

Now in all the delegate callbacks you just check which collectionView is calling you.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (collectionView == self.collectionViewA) {
    // do collection view A action
  } else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewB) {
    // do collection view B action
  }
}
```

---

Another pattern that may be useful is to just create two separate dataSource/delegate objects to handle the different collection views.